# How to get number of users with static query?

Tags: drupal-8

I want to get a number of users in Drupal 8.

```
$connection = \Drupal::database();
$query = $connection->query('SELECT count(*)' FROM {users})；
$results = $query->fetchAll();
$results = json_decode(json_encode($results),true);
print_r($results);
```

It displays an output:

```
Array([0]=>Array([count(*)]=>10));
```

But there are just 2 users on my site for now.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, quantity FROM {goods} WHERE vid = :vid";
$result = db_query($sql, array(':vid' => $vid));
if ($result) {
  while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    // Do something with:
    // $row['name']
    // $row['quantity']
  }
}
```

or

```
$query = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM {node}");
$records = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($records as $record) {
  // Do something.
}
```